# On click on <div>, focus input field - How to do this with React / Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, flux

That's basically my question. I have different containers & components. If a certain div is clicked in a certain container or component, I want to set the focus to the input field of a different container/component.

However, I do not know how to do this with Redux. I could dispatch an action

```
export const focusInputField = () => {
  return {
    type: "FOCUS_INPUTFIELD"
  }
}
```

but I am not sure what to do in my reducer? I have a reducer for the currently displayed person, for all the persons and also one for the currently selected (school) class. It is not obvious to me now, how to integrate the state of the input field in here. Maybe I am thinking to object-oriented?

But even if there was a state for the input field, I would not be quite sure how to change focus in the React component then. How could I just watch that state change and then, if the state changes from false to true say, change the focus?

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a state in for the corresponding reducer

Dispatch an action as

```
export const focusInputField = () => {
  return {
    type: "FOCUS_INPUTFIELD"
  }
}
```

In the reducer

```
var initialState={inFocus: false}
const someReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
       case FOCUS_INPUTFIELD:
           return {
               ...state, inFocus: true
           }
       case FOCUSOUT_INPUTFIELD: 
           return {
               ...state, inFocus: false
           }
       default: return state
   }
}
export default someReducer;
```

Then in the containers componentWillReciveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(this.props.inFocus !== newProps.inFocus) {
          if(newProps.inFocus == true) {
             this.inputRef.focus();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: To set `this.inputRef` use the [`ref` function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) when rendering the component and remember to dispatch the `FOCUSOUT_INPUTFIELD` action in the [`onBlur` function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#focus-events).

Comment: @MichaelPeyper, yes you are right , I should be set using callback and that's y I wrote this in my Answer instead of this.refs.inputRef

Comment: I assumed you knew, my comment is more targeted at anyone looking at this answer and hopefully filling in a few blanks for them.

Comment: I understand as I will also edit my answer to fill in you suggestion, as soon as I reach home.